# Can we make the alignment of VF page sections dynamic with bootstrap?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, javascript, community

I have a requirement where I am overriding the Edit and New page for a standard sObject. I have used a custom settings for page section header and page section's fieldsets. I can iterate over these custom settings records to render in some specific alignment. Say two column or one column. Whatever I do it will be common for all sections.
***Is there any dynamic way to set the alignments for sections via bootstrap. Few sections as one column or some as two columns etc.***

Thanks,
Smriti

Comment: Are you using col-lg-6 for div in which you are showing field

Comment: Yes, I am using it. I wanted a logic to make this col-lg-(dynamic parameter). I did  this based on a custom setting where I caught the logic for layouts (either 1 col, or 2 cols and so on).  This was sorted this way.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted a logic to make this **col-lg-(dynamic parameter). I did this based on a custom setting where I caught the logic for layouts (either 1 col, or 2 cols and so on).** It was sorted this way.

Thanks all!
Regards,
Smriti